# Angular: Conditional parent component

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Consider the markup below

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="isModal; else content" >
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
  <div
    role="dialog"
    class="modal fade show d-block">
    <ng-container
      class="modal-dialog"
      *ngIf="true; then content">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>`enter code here`
<ng-template #content>
    <!-- children here -->
</ng-template>
```

Depending on the modal state `isModal` the content container `#content` will be attached to a different parent `DOM` element.

- Problem

The problem is that the state `isModal` can change after the component creation, which leads to `*ngIf` being computed and thus removes the `#content` from the `DOM` in order to place it on a different parent. **I am aware that this is the expected behavior of `*ngIf`**.

- What I am looking for

I am looking for a way to achieve this **conditional parent** without destroying the children when the parent changes.

any help is welcome. Cheers

Comment: Why not make a second `*ngIf="!modal || child"` ?

Comment: please elaborate, I didn't quite get the idea

Comment: `<child1
  *ngIf="!isModal || child1" >
</child1>`

Comment: @Swoox that will render the content outside of the modal parent

Comment: Isn't that what you want if it isn't a modal? You need two ngIf's. I'd recommend putting your content in its own component, and put it in a modal container _and_ outside it and just have two instances of it. You can't conditionally remove a parent element in Angular, that's just not how it works.

Comment: well, it is a bit more tricky than this.
So I end up removing ngIf and surrounding my content with two div for which I set classes depending on the modal state. As a downside for this approach I have two div which are useless if state is not modal. But it works! cheers

Comment: if the child depends on the parent or parent from child ngIf wont destroy the component